# FormItemIcon smartgwt with gwt platform wrong href

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I am facing a problem since long time with `Smartgwt & gwtp`.

`FormItemIcon` is an `element` of `SmartGWT`. When adding a `click handler` to this element, 
It add a `"click" event` to it from what I understand and `GWTP` is using extensively the `history` which is the goal, but since this element adding a `<a href="#"` instead of 
`<a href="javascript();">` it cause to mess with history.

The question, Why when I add a `clickHeandler` to a `FormItemIcon` it adds a `<a href="#"` element.

Thank for you help,
Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing how you use the FormItemIcon and the related form item. I would suggest you have a look here at their [showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_details_icons) as well.